# Error in p4 submit of a file in a branch

Tags: perforce

I have a question about p4 submit.

At work I have created a branch in perforce, and branched out from a main codeline(mainline) and got the latest revisions of all the files of a certain folder say folder1, from the depot into my workspace.

Now I changed a file inside folder1, say file.cpp. So I first Checked out that file from that branch into my workspace.

Now I wanted to submit this version to depot as next revision in the branch codeline (Not mainline - NO Integration intended, just want to create next revision of that file in my branch and submit to depot)

I use p4 visual client. When I right click on this changed file, file.cpp and say submit that file alone, it gave mer error:
verify job validation failed: MISSING JOB.

Job needs to be associated with change.

Question:  How does one create this association between job and change.

What is to be done to fix this error and submit my file to create its next revision in the branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after another agonising trial and errors, found what i was doing wrong:

1. After we say file.cpp context Right Click, Submit, One has to create a new job.
2. In the window that comes up, enter description of job , username. When job is created successfully. it would say something like job5436060
3. Then control comes back to previous iwndow submit file. There add this job.
   Earlier I was adding just the numerical part of job i.e. 5436060 , which lead to errors of job not found and it threw me offtrack completely.

   What we need  to enter while adding a job is **job5436060** Now it will find the job, add successfully that job and then the submit command was successfull.

:-) Little joys you have, after anguishing over something you think should be straightforward but struggle after you miss something simple but fundamental.

Comment: This isn't normally necessary - I guess your perforce server has a pre-commit hook to check that every commit has a job attached. I guess you'll want to create pending change lists with the changed files, and attach a job there.

Answer (score 0):

Your perforce server must have a pre-submit [trigger](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/cmdref/triggers.html) set up which requires a job with every submitted changeset. You'll have to (create and) add a job to the pending changeset before you submit it successfully.